# OnClick Event not firing when I am specifying action url in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web

I need to redirect the user to paypal account. But before that I want to collect name and email for that user. So I am using the following code.

```
<form id="paypalForm" method="post" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"
                 target="_top" runat="server">
    <div>
        <label>
            Full Name:<span>*</span></label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="name" runat="server" CssClass="large form-poshytip" title="Enter your Full Name."></asp:TextBox>
        <label>
            E-Mail:<span>*</span></label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="email" runat="server" CssClass="large form-poshytip" title="Enter Email Address."></asp:TextBox>
        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick" />
        <div id="partnerFormButton">
            <br />
            <asp:ImageButton runat="server" Name="btnSubmit" Text="          Next          "
                ID="btnSubmit" 
                ImageUrl="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" 
                onclick="btnSubmit_Click" CausesValidation="False" ></asp:ImageButton>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Code Behind code:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        //some code
    }
```

But the problem is that OnClick event doesn't firing and it redirects to the specified action url.

What can be the problem?

Thank you so much in advance...!!

Comment: asp.net doesn't support "MessageBox.Show", did you add a breakpoint at the btnSubmit_Click to see if the breakpoint being hit or not?

Comment: there should be some problem with event binding with control

Comment: @user2191496: i have added a breakpoint at the btnSubmit_Click but it is not being hit..

Comment: I've updated my answer, please take a look at it. If you still don't understand what is happening, you should probably read about the basics - how ASP.NET events work, what is a postback, how POST requests are generated on webpages etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not how ASP.NET events work. Events are fired after postback is made and you are preventing the postback by submitting the form. You need to decide what to do - either submit data with the form (like what you are doing now) and not use OnClick event or use the event and remove action and method parameters from form.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

To explain it further: an event will not fire right after you click the button. What happens is that a POST request is being made to the same page with the page state passed in the ViewState. In other words - pressing the button in ASP.NET by default works kind of like a link to the same page (it's a veeeery simplified explanation though). Events are fired only after that request is made and after the page is loaded again - see the link above.

What you are doing right now is forcing the request to go to another page. Even though the button 'wants' to do a postback, the `action` parameter in your `<form>` points the request somewhere else. Since the postback isn't made and your page isn't loaded again, the event will not fire.

Comment: Appreciated well explained.

Comment: +1, yes use one of them either the onClick event or the action parameter

Answer (score 0):

IISTe Technologies is going to introduce a blog for their student and other developers where they can find and share their problem and solution regarding c, c++, .NET java, PHP and others, here you one can find the exact solution of their programming problems.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have specified the action in the form tag.

You can redirect the page to "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" in the click event. For if u specif action then you you wont be able to sumbit the data of the for. You won't get the values.

Answer (score 0):

It will never go to the click event code block you have written. Because you are posting the page to paypal page instead of self.

Try this:

- Remove action attribute from form.
- Write click event as

  protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
          {
              var target = @"https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
              Response.Status = "307 Temporary Redirect";
              Response.AddHeader("Location", target);
          }

Comment: I cant use Response.AddHEader as I need to submit hidden values within form.

Comment: What do you want to do in click event? Can you pass the form values to your page using ajax call on button click and then redirect to paypal page using javascript, if ajax call success.